# Does Russian have a word meaning 'snarky'?

Tags: перевод, английский

In American English we have the word 'snarky', meaning 'sharply critical; cutting; snide'. A Russian translator suggests the word элегантного, but this does not seem to have the same sense as the English word. How would this concept be expressed in Russian?

What about the following: Придирчивый, язвительный, ехидный, резкий в высказываниях, язва, or
Сварливый?

Comment: There's probably no precise single word equivalent. All of your translations will do to some extent or another. Also едкий, колкий, желчный.

Comment: [Here](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=snarky&l1=1) the translation "шикарный, элегантный" is marked as "slang".

Comment: A few more references: on-line dictionaries [Академик](http://translate.academic.ru/snarky/en/ru/) и [Lingvo](http://www.lingvo-online.ru/en/Translate/ru-en/snarky). And another possible translations: ядовитый и саркастичный/саркастический.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned, there would probably no *precise single word* equivalent.

Yet another translation, which I think is very appropriate, is: "**злобный; ехидный**"
(see [yandex dictionaries](http://m.slovari.yandex.ru/translate.xml?text=snide&lang=en)).

Answer (score 2):

See also циник http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA

http://otvet.mail.ru/question/27719027

and ёрничать http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/79476-chto-takoe-jornichat.html

http://otvet.mail.ru/question/2020108

http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C